# how to get creation time of index template in elastisearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I want to check that which template created first across multiple templates.

I have tried `GET _cat/templates` API but it does not return creation time.

So, how can I get the creation time of the template in elastisearch?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO.

It is not possible to get those information from the api endpoint but if you want you can use `Version` attribute in the template to check which version you are storing in the cluster or you can have `_meta` field in your template that you can add information about the [template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html).

You can find information about `_meta` field [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-meta-field.html).